# Explanation of all columns in size command output?

Tags: linux

After executing a size command I got the following output:

```
size main.out   

       text    data     bss     dec     hex filename  
       1207     552       8    1767     6e7 main.out
```

I understood the meaning of the `text`, the `data` and the `bss` segment.

What is the meaning of the `dec` and `hex` columns?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/80352

Comment: Why is this tagged C

Comment: `text(1207)` + `data(552)` + `bbs(8)` = `dec(1767)`

Comment: `1767` is the total size of the object file and `0x6e7 = 1767`

Comment: 6e7 is 1767 in hexadecimal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**text** gives you the size of the [text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) segment (or code segment).

**data** gives you the size of the [data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) segment.

**bss** gives you the size of the [block started by symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment.

**dec** is the size of the text, data and bss size added together in decimal, and **hex** is the same number in hexadecimal.