# Is my BSS section in critical size?

Tags: c, arm

I have written a small application for my heating system in my apartment, at the end of compilation I am becoming the following output :

```
 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size'
arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "Phaethon_F446.elf"
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
142935      924   77140  220999   35f47 Phaethon_F446.elf
```

I am using the STM32F446RE with 128 KB RAM, if I am correct, the bss section needs 75KB of RAM; that means more than 50% of the RAM is gone.

- Am I wrong?
- Kills bss my RAM or this value is represented wrong from the compiler?
- What should I change in my software?

Comment: What do you mean by 'is gone'? How bss can 'kill' your RAM? You have 128KB of ram, and your firmware uses 78064 bytes of RAM, so it's ok. Maybe see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303014/explanation-of-all-columns-in-size-command-output)?

Comment: If you are using a lot of bss by design then there is nothing broken here, is it more than you expected?  Have you tried reducing the amount of bss data?

Comment: You could run `arm-none-eabi-objdump -x` to see the size of individual symbols. You can use the usual shell tools to grep and sort the output to find the ones taking most RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, according to the report, the ~50% of the RAM is being taken by .bss. To be sure, you could generate the map file to find out how (or where) the variables are being allocated (-Wl,-Map=output.map).

Regarding a solution, you have to optimise the software (are all the variables needed? Are you using compiler optimisations as -O3/... [options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) ? Can you re-use variables?) I have no idea about your code/algorithms/etc, but it looks like a lot of bytes just for a heating system.

The linker script will show you the borders (that is, the current size) of the .bss section (and how your memory is splitted), just in case you want to modify it (you can choose how the memory is distributed).

Comment: I am using also a GUI and a Touchscreen, maybe this is the reason but I think it is a too large amount of memory consumption.

Comment: @poprock That sounds more normal.

Comment: Make sure you use -Os to optimize code for size. Although I doubt it will affect bss size. The Touchscreen might keep a framebuffer in memory, which would be a (relatively) huge chunk of memory. As Jose suggested output the map file and check what ends up in bss and see if any large chunks are from your code. If so try to make them smaller.